# Problema con Youtube Extractor con C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, youtube

Buenos Días

Estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación con WindowsForm en C# para **descargar audios de YouTube**.
Utilizo un paquete Nuget llamada **YoutubeExtractor**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
private bool DescargarAudio()
        {
            bool vf = false;
            try
            {
                VideoInfo video = videoInfos.Where(info => info.CanExtractAudio).FirstOrDefault();//OrderByDescending(info => info.AudioBitrate)
                if (video.RequiresDecryption)
                {
                    DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
                }
                var audioDownloader = new AudioDownloader(video, Application.StartupPath+video.Title + video.AudioExtension,320);
                audioDownloader.Execute();
                vf = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex.Message;
            }
            return vf;
        }
```

El problema es que esta línea me devuelve **null**:

```
VideoInfo video = videoInfos.Where(info => info.CanExtractAudio).FirstOrDefault();//OrderByDescending(info => info.AudioBitrate)
```

Y me debería devolver un algún elemento de la lista. Probé con varios links y me da siempre lo mismo.
No se si podrá ser un problema de la dll o estoy haciendo algo mal.

¿Tienen alguna solución o hay algún otro paquete para realizar lo mismo?

Un saludos para todos.

Felices Fiestas.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código donde instancias `videoInfos`.

Comment: Hola, es estática la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando un poco el repositorio del proyecto, observo gente reportando errores similares al tuyo: https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor/issues

Teniendo en cuenta que la actividad del proyecto está [bastante inconstante](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor/commits/master), es posible que la librería tenga errores. Te sugeriría usar otro proyecto como [YoutubeExplode](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode).

EDITO: Otra opción es usar una combinación de librerías. Por ejemplo, puedes usar  `MediaToolkit` para extraer el audio de un video que ya tengas. Fíjate en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39878726/2517733).

EDITO2: Esto también te puede servir: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeMusicDownloader

Comment: Hola, ¿tienes algún ejemplo hecho para la descarga de audio? que no sean los que muestren en github. @Racso

Comment: No. Si necesitas algo más documentado, hay otro NuGet llamado `MediaToolkit` para el que te puedo citar un ejemplo. Ya lo pongo en la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la información.